# How to autowire classes in unmanaged instances?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I have a class that gets created within server startup. It serves as entry method for the client application. I cannot change this behaviour.

Though I'd like to use Spring `@Autowired` inside this unmanaged class. I read that aspectj weaving might be the way to go. It seems to already execute accoding to logs:

```
2014-01-28 13:11:10,156 INFO org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver: Using a reflective load-time weaver for class loader: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
```

But still my injected `Dao` service is `null`. What might be missing?

```
@WebListener
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
        @Override
            public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            new TestService().run(); //throws NPE
        }
}

@Configurable
class TestService extends AbstractLegacyService {       
    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //dao is always null
        dao.find();
    }
}


@Component
class Doa dao;
```

enable weaving (tomcat):

```
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `web.xml`? Especially the part where the context listeners are registered.

Comment: it's registered by annotation. The web.xml does not define any listeners.

Comment: I think you still need to have a bean definition for TestService to use as a template. Also don't forget your component scan.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OP uses the load-time weaver. The load-time weaver injects objects created with the `new` operator if the are `@Configurable`. It's for bean whose lifecycle is managed outside the spring container.

Comment: @RenéLink And according to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) `Spring will configure new instances of the annotated type ( Account in this case) using a bean definition (typically prototype-scoped) with the same name as the fully-qualified type name ( com.xyz.myapp.domain.Account).`

Comment: @RenéLink Also, `@ComponentScan` is missing so `@Autowired` wouldn't be picked up.

Comment: Of course `Dao` is annotated with `@Component` so it should be picked up by spring.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just tried a small setup with a main class, a spring context xml (without component scan) and an bean like the one defined by membersound (@Configurable, @Autowired) and it works. Sadly I have not way to show you that code since this questions is not about this.

Comment: @RenéLink I'll try it when I get to work as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok. Do you know if there is another way to share some code on stackoverflow than through questions?

Comment: @RenéLink Made a chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46240/spring-load-time-weaving

Comment: @membersound I think your problem has something to do with the listener order. If the `MyContextListener`s `contextInitialized` gets invoked before the `ContextLoaderListener` has a chance to start the spring container than the LTW can not access the spring container. I m not really sure but I would give it a try. Maybe you can set breakpoints in `ContextLoaderListener` and `MyContextListener`. Then you will see which one gets invoked first.

Comment: Maybe we're getting closer with this: I don't have any `ContextLoaderListener` defined. Only listener defined is the `@WebListener`. But I think `@Configuration` is the annotation-based replacement for `ContextLoaderListener`?

Comment: @membersound come to the chat that Sotirios Delimanolis opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure that the `ContextLoaderListener` is invoked before the `MyContextListener` gets invoked.

The `ContextLoaderListener` initializes the spring container and the load-time weaver can only inject the dependencies of the `TestService` if the spring container is initialized.

Comment: I just discovered that if I change the implementation to `@WebListener class MyContextListener extends ContextLoaderListener` and override init & destroy methods accordingly similar to my post, the whole spring injection just works as expected.

Comment: Yes ok, that is also a solution. Depending on what the `MyContextListener` does and if you want to use it in another context (maybe a non spring context) it makes sense to extend from `ContextLoaderListener` or not.